# How to customize mat-form-field(things like background, color, padding etc) in angular material version 15?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am working in a project which uses angular material(version 15) elements, I got some requirements where i have to customize mat-form-field(need to change bg color, color and padding etc). I have searched like a hell, but did not get any solution for it. Please help me to customize mat-form-field in version 15. I know how to customize till version 13 but above that don't know. any answers would be appreciable.

please have a look at my code which is working absolutely fine in version 12.
some.component.html:->

```
        <mat-form-field class="opaque">
            <textarea matInput
                      #editUserPrompt
                      cdkTextareaAutosize cdkAutosizeMinRows="1" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="10"
                      formControlName="userQueryText"
                      (keydown)="onEditUserPromptKeyDown($event)"></textarea>
            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix matTooltip="Send message" (click)="onEditSendClick()" [disabled]="!editForm.valid"><mat-icon>done</mat-icon></button>
            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix matTooltip="Cancel" (click)="onEditCancelClick()"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
            <mat-error>
                {{ getErrorMessage(editForm, 'userQueryText') }}
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

some.component.scss:->

```
        .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
    border: none !important;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.mat-form-field.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline > div.mat-form-field-wrapper > div.mat-form-field-flex > div.mat-form-field-infix {
    padding: 0.1em 0.25em 0.9em 0.25em !important;
    color: white;
}

.mat-form-field.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline > div.mat-form-field-wrapper > div.mat-form-field-flex > div.mat-form-field-infix > span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper {
    top: -1.5em;
}

.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
    transform: translateY(-1.5em) scale(.1);
    width: 133.33333%;
}
```